Required YAML template from a different Azure DevOps organization
I know that it is possible to use a yaml template from a different organization using this but, how can I enforce it as a required yaml template on a service connection and/or a variable group? Seems that in the required yaml template dialogue you can only specify templates in the same organization:

Can this be achieved? Which is the right syntax?

The required yaml template supports specifying templates from the different organization.

how can I enforce it as a required yaml template on a service connection and/or a variable group?

Here are the steps:
Step1: Create an Azure Repos/Team Foundation Server service connection in Project Settings -> Service connections.
Step2: Add the remote repo resource in YAML Pipeline to use the template file in another organization.
For example:
resources:
  repositories: 
    - repository: remoteRepo # Simple name to reference this repository at a later step
      type: git
      name: Test Project/mvcexam
      endpoint: xxx # Azure DevOps service connection
      ref: refs/heads/master 
variables:
 - group:  test
extends:
    template: template.yml@remoteRepo

Step3: Add the Required Yaml template to Variable Group or Service Connection -> Approvals and checks.

Result:

For more detailed info, you can refer to this doc: Security through templates

Hi @Kevin Lu-MSFT. I am a bit confused. How is Azure DevOps able to determine with these parameters on the dialogue that the required yaml template is in the other organization instead of in the project "Test Project" of the same organization?

@Josto Good question!  I can understand your confusion now. The required template check currently only checks the specified project/repo/yml file. It does not check the organization because we cannot specify organization information in the required  template check. If a project/repo/yaml file with the same name appears, it will also pass the check. Therefore, we need to avoid referencing projects/repo/templates with the same name in two orgs for the time being.

I can fully understand your concern.  I suggest that you can submit a suggestion ticket: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/AzureDevOps/suggest to let the required template check to support organization parameter.

@Josto Currently, you can check if the required template check if can work when using the template from another organization. Feel free to let me know if you have any further questions.

Strictly speaking, the answer is correct since the required template can be in a different organization, so I've accepted it as valid. Nevertheless, the ambiguity with the repo location could mean an issue for somebody (not for me, at least at this point).
